# Microsoft N-Layer sample

Tags: .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, architecture, n-layer

What do you think about http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/ ? I am interesting in data access implementation (UnitOfWork, repositories, transactions). Is it the "best" example of implementing this issue on microsoft technologies ?
If you have some interesting samples or posts describing implementation UnitOfWork + Repository with transaction management please share them.

EDIT: I just want to know some thoughtes of expert about this implementation or some usefull links which can help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Consider narrowing down the scope of your question, otherwise it is too open ended to have an answer. Perhaps stick to critiques of the sample you have mentioned. That would still be a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this sample : http://nhibernateasp.codeplex.com/ but is based on NHibernate that is a good solution for data access layer.

Answer (score 0):

The link [microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com](http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/),mentioned in you post has been obsoleted.

There are samples(WPF, WCF, Windows Form, ASP.NET,MVC and etc...) based on Microsoft Layered Architecture Pattern here: [Layered Architecture Samples for .NET](https://layersample.codeplex.com/)